# Concatenate time value to match row's Date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that compares just the times in a `Datetime` column.
If the criteria is met then I need the the column to update and concatenated a time value to the corresponding date in that row.

Here is the SQL statement,

```
declare @first datetime
set @first = '2016/10/10 06:47:16.123'
declare @second datetime
set @second = '2016/10/10 10:47:16.123'
declare @myTime datetime
set @myTime = '2016/10/10 00:15:16.123'


 UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL        
        SET Time_Data_1 = CASE  
             WHEN CAST(Time_Data_1 AS time) 
             BETWEEN CAST(@first AS time) AND CAST(@second AS time) 
             THEN CAST(Date_Data AS date) + CAST(@myTime AS time)                        
        ELSE NULL       
        END
     WHERE Staff_No = 1903 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/2/1' AND '2016/3/1'
```

After the criteria is met I need this line below to get the date from that row, from a column named `Date_Data` (data type is `DATE`) and concatenate it with just a time value into a column named `Time_Data_1` (data type is `DATETIME`)

```
THEN CAST(Date_Data AS date) + CAST(@myTime AS time)
```

Presently I am getting an error,

> Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.

I believe this was able to be done before 2008 , but I am on SQL server 2014 ,How do you go about doing something like this.

Comment: you need one more cast to add time cast(cast(Date_Data as date) as datetime) + cast(CAST(@myTime AS time) as datetime)

Comment: @nazark, thanks that fixed it. Working now.

Comment: @nazark, yes, I will up vote and mark as answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type should be same while adding time, try

```
cast(cast(Date_Data as date) as datetime) + cast(CAST(@myTime AS time) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2012 you can do this:

```
   DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( 
   datepart(YEAR, Date_Data), 
   datepart(MONTH, Date_Data), 
   datepart(DAY, Date_Data), 
   datepart(HOUR, @myTime ), 
   datepart(MINUTE, @myTime), 
   datepart(SECOND, @myTime), 
   datepart(MILLISECOND, @myTime) 
    )
```

On anterior version you can use this function too:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DATETIME2FROMPARTS](
  @year int,
  @month int,
  @day int,
  @hour int,
  @minute int,
  @second int,
  @fractions int,
  @precision int)
    RETURNS datetime2(7)
    AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN
    DATEADD(NANOSECOND, POWER(10, 9-@precision)*@fractions, 
    DATEADD(SECOND, @second, 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, @minute, 
    DATEADD(HOUR, @hour, 
    DATEADD(DAY, @day-1, 
    DATEADD(MONTH, @month-1, 
    DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 
    CAST(CAST(0 AS datetime) AS datetime2(7)))))))));
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a date is a date datatype, and a time is a time datatype.  You are looking at the string of those values, which looks like a datetime datatype, but they are apples and oranges to SQL Server.

But if you normalize them both into what YOU are seeing (a varchar string), you can convert that string into a datetime:

```
    select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), @date) + ' ' + convert(varchar(12), @time))
```

Comment: I intend to up vote the answer as I have it half working, but it does produce some strange results. this is what I did, `Date_Data` is a column, `convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), Date_Data) + ' ' + convert(varchar(12), @myTime))`